# How to recreate Docker container?

Tags: postgresql, docker

I'm new to docker and I'm using docker compose. For some reason my postgres container is now broken

I'm trying this command `docker-compose up --no-deps --build db`

And it's returning me this:

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Javier:goxo.api javier$ docker-compose up --no-deps --build db
Recreating testapi_db_1
Attaching to testapi_db_1
db_1   | LOG:  database system was shut down at 2017-04-20 17:19:05 UTC
db_1   | LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
db_1   | LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
db_1   | LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
```

Whenever I try to connect (with the same connection arguemnts than before) I get this:

```
^[[Adb_1   | FATAL:  database "test" does not exist
```

This is part of my docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "3700:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_HOST: "127.0.0.1"
      POSTGRES_DB: "test"
      POSTGRES_USER: "postgres"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "postgres1"
    tmpfs:
      - /tmp
      - /var/run/postgresql
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./config/postgres-initdb.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/initdb.sh
```

Any ideas on how can I recreate the docker image to be how it was before? It was working as it was created the first time

Thanks

**EDIT 1:** If I run `docker-compose build && docker-compose up`

Terminal throws this:

```
db uses an image, skipping
```

**EDIT 2:** This command does not create database again neither:

```
docker-compose up --force-recreate --abort-on-container-exit --build db
```

Comment: Just a side note to your question: You must know that container with database must be created for test purposes only. This is only one of many articles that explain why: https://myopsblog.wordpress.com/2017/02/06/why-databases-is-not-for-containers/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

have you tried to rebuild your single postgres container?

```
docker build -t <postgrescontainer>
```

or with docker-compose:

```
docker-compose up --build
```

to recreate the images and not use the old 'used' ones.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at the images on your system with

`docker images`

which should show your image, and then

`docker history --no-trunc your_image`

should show the commands used for the creation of the image

This my be insufficient, as when you see something like

`ADD * /opt`

you do not know exactly which files were copied, and what thoses files contained

There is also dockerfile-from-image

https://github.com/CenturyLinkLabs/dockerfile-from-image

which seems to have a bug recently (I do not know if it is fixed)